# Angularjs directive for sorting bootstrap tables

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My app have multiple bootstrap tables and i want to create a global angularjs directive for sorting these tables to use this custome directive.

I have tried few but they don't help me enough what i want.

Please find plunk below for example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BFkWWWtuZK4x6dHiEy3I

In the above example is not sorting as the scope is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your directive isn't manipulating the outside scope.  It can't do that because it doesn't have access to the variables in the parent scope because javascript is copy by value.  You can manipulate what you are passed, but you can't manipulate the value of variable that was passed to you.  So angularjs wants you to put objects between you and the references you are binding between so manipulations in across isolated scopes will propagate back to the caller.  So if you modify your app to use that it works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6sqQZk

Now it's a bit messy for my tastes.  I'd probably move the whole table definition into the directive, and let it handle the whole thing.  It would also make it easier to setup a sorting table without all of the plumbing, but that's up to you.

Comment: I have added date column and it doesn't work for date column,help appreciated